# Get Sum of Products in same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below data set:

[image]

Let's assume it starts in `A1`. I would like to calculate the `Total Cost`for January by taking each `Count` and multiplying by the `Rate` below it.

I currently have the following, nonsensical formula:

`Total Cost = (B1 * B2) + (B3 * B4) + (B5 * B6) + ... + (Bn + Bn+1) for n > 0`

Is there a whizzy way to do this using an Excel formula? Perhaps something with `SUMPRODUCT()`? But I can't seem to get that to work the way I need it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified example:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5="Count"),B1:B5*B2:B6)
```